# Execute Macro inside SQL statement

Tags: sql, macros, sas, sas-macro

#### The Situation:

I have a table `mytable` with two columns: `tablename` and `tablefield`:

```
|-----------|------------|
| tablename | tablefield |
|-----------|------------|
| table1    | id         |
| table2    | date       |
| table3    | etc        |
|-----------|------------|
```

**My core objective here** is basically, make a `Select` **for each** of these tablenames, showing the `MAX()` value of its corresponding tablefield.

```
Proc SQL;
Select MAX(id) From table1;
Select MAX(date) From table2;
Select MAX(etc) From table3;
Quit;
```

*ps: The solution have to pull the data from the table, so whether the table change its values, the solutions will make its changes also.*

#### What I have tried:

From the most of my attempts, this is the most sofisticated and I believe the nearest from the solution:

```
proc sql;
create table table_associations (
    memname varchar(255), dt_name varchar(255)
);

Insert Into table_associations 
values ("table1", "id")
values ("table2", "date")
values ("table3", "etc");
quit;

%Macro Max(field, table);
Select MAX(&field.) From &table.;
%mend;

proc sql;
Select table, field, (%Max(field,table))
From LIB.table_associations
quit;
```

Creating the Macro, my intend is clear but, for this example, I should solve 2 problems:

- Execute a macro inside an `SQL` Statement; And
- Make the macro understand its String value parameter as an `SQL` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a data step, you can use `call execute` to do what you're describing.

```
%Macro Max(field, table);
proc sql;
Select MAX(&field.) From &table.;
quit;
%mend;

data _null_;
    set table_associations;
    call execute('%MAX('||field||','||table||')');
run;
```

Comment: Do you know what is this error saying? `File LIB.TABLE_ASSOCIATIONS.DATA does not exist` *I just have to solve this to test if your answer solved my problem*. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Delete the `LIB.`.  I included it because it was in your example code, but I see now that `table_associations` is in the work directory, and the libname should be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not necessary here as you can just generate the code using `put` statements in the data step:

```
filename gencode temp;

data _null_;
  set table_associations end=eof;
  file gencode;
  if _n_=1 then put 'proc sql;';
  put 'select max(' tablefield ') from ' tablename ';';
  if eof then put 'quit;';
run;

%include gencode / source2;
filename gencode clear;
```

The code is written to the a temporary file named 'gencode'. You could make this file permanent if you want. `_n_=1` and `end=eof` are used to print the statements before and after the queries. Finally, `%include gencode` runs the code and the `source2` option prints the code to the log.